# File size check, Linux

Tags: linux, bash, loops

**File size check**

```
file_path="/home/d-vm/"
cd $file_path
# file_path directory
file=($(cat video.txt | xargs ls -lah | awk '{ print $9}'))
# get name in video.txt --- two files for example VID_141523.mp4 VID_2_141523.mp4
minimumsize=1
actualsize=$(wc -c <"$file")
if [ $actualsize -ge $minimumsize ]; then
    echo $file size $actualsize bytes
else
    echo error $file size 0 bytes
fi
```

VID_141523.mp4 file corrupted during conversion. its size 0 bytes

Script output---- `error VID_20220709_141523.mp4 size 0 bytes`

**video.txt**

- VID_141523.mp4
- VID_2_141523.mp4

**How to add this construct to the loop ?**
It should check all files in the list **video.txt**

Comment: Don't use `ls` in scripts. Use `stat` to get file size.

Comment: You define `file` as an array, which makes sense, because you want to store more than one filename. However a bit below, you use it as a scalar, when you write `<"$file"`. This does not make sense. What do you want to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably mean - "how to loop instead of this: `file=($(cat video.txt | xargs ls -lah | awk '{ print $9}'))`" (which is pretty horrible by itself <sup>(*)</sup>).

You should just use a `while` loop:

```bash
cat video.txt | while read file; do
   # something with $file
done
```

Also, please use `stat -c%s FILE` instead of `wc` (which, BTW, also takes a file - you can use `wc -c FILE` instead of using input redirection), as that looks just at the file system information to check the size, instead of loading and counting each byte.

<sub>(*) doing `ls -lah` and then `awk '{print$9}'` is the same as just doing `ls`, but there are other issues with this code that is very not bash idiomatic.</sub>

Comment: `cat` is totally useless here. Simply do: `while read file; do : "do something with $file"; done < video.txt`

Comment: Correct, but the postfix syntax often confuses new users, so I avoid it for answering such questions.

Answer (score 2):

To read a file size `stat` is the best for use-case here. On a linux machine with GNU stat

```bash
$ stat --printf="%s" one
4
```

This can be looped like

```bash
#!/bin/bash
while read -r file ; do
    if [ "$(stat --printf="%s" "$file")" -gt 0 ]
        then
            echo "$file" yes
        else 
            echo "$file" no
    fi
done < video.txt
```

This is too complicated approach in my opinion. Just use [find](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)

```bash
$ touch zero
$ echo one > one
$ ll
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 sverma  wheel     4B Jul 11 16:20 one
-rw-r--r--  1 sverma  wheel     0B Jul 11 16:20 zero
```

`one` is a 4 byte file. Use `-size` predicate. Here `+` means greater than, `-type f` means only files

```bash
$ find . -type f -size +0 -print
./one
```

You can add a filter for names with something like

```
$ find . -name '*.mp4' -type f -size +0
```

Comment: Mostly good, but always add double quotes around variable expansion and command substitution: `if [ "$(stat --printf='%s' "$file")" -gt 0 ] ;`, `printf %s yes\n' "$file"`... Also semicolon `;` is useless at end of line. See what static analysis shellcheck.net has to tell you.